# Header about MIME email

Tags: shell-script, mutt

I want to send HTML email like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=lazuardi
--lazuardi
```

After that email. I have html email.

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<html>
<body>
......
This is HTML message
</body>
</html>
--lazuardi
```

Then i also include plain text

```
Content-type: text/plain
this is plain text message
--lazuardi--
```

Am I wrong that I include header in my body.html?
Where should I put the header?
I using Mutt email client, everytime I send the email, mutt always give me this message: No boundary parameter found! [report this error]...
Could not send the message.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at [RFC1521 "MIME Part One",  Appendix C "A Complex Multipart Example"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521#appendix-C).

It seems that you need to put a blank line after headers.

Comment: @weredriver thanks for your answer, I'll try..